# Is Controller.HttpContext (HttpContextBase) thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

If you have the following code in a (non Core) ASP.NET MVC 5 project:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASPApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public Task<ActionResult> UnSafeThreadAccess()
        {
            PrintThreadId("UnSafeThreadAccess entry");
            var synchronisationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            return Task.Delay(2).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                PrintThreadId("UnSafeThreadAccess continueWith");
                var controllerContext = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["q"];
                var content = $"Responding to {System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["q"]}";
                return Content(content) as ActionResult;
            });
        } 

        private static void PrintThreadId(string threadName)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{threadName}: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

I knew that accessing `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` inside the `ContinueWith` is bad, since it is bound to the entry thread of the controller. The point of this code is to illustrate why awaiting the `Task.Delay` is necessary in this example.

However I was a bit surprised that the `HttpContext` property of the controller can be accessed inside `ContinueWith`. How is this possible? I know the type of the property is not `HttpContext` but `HttpContextBase`, however I was expecting that this would just call through to the static HttpContext instance.

Comment: Why is `ContinueWith` necessary here? If you have an async operation that needs to remain context aware you can await it, just **do not** `ConfigureAwait(false)` it.

Comment: Yes I'm aware what I'm doing makes no sense, but that is exactly the point. The code should crash because I'm accessing the context on another ThreadPool thread. The actual question is why `var controllerContext = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["q"];` is valid at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> However I was a bit surprised that the `HttpContext` property of the controller can be accessed inside `ContinueWith`. How is this possible? [...], however I was expecting that this would just call through to the static `HttpContext` instance.

Digging in the sources reveals that `Controller.HttpContext` is not a plain call-through to `HttpContext.Current` but HTTP context is retrieved from the request context ( `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext`) which actually stores a reference to the current `HttpContextBase` instance:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/v3.2.6/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L87
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/v3.2.6/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerContext.cs#L71
https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4.6.2/System.Web/Routing/RequestContext.cs#L23

In this sense it's safe to access `Controller.HttpContext` from another thread than the entry thread of the request.

However, [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) the following about `HttpContext`:

> This object is ready for garbage collection when the HttpRequest is completed. Its usage after the request completes could lead to undefined behavior, such as a NullReferenceException.
>
> This object is only available in the thread controlled by ASP.NET. Usage in background threads could lead to undefined behavior.

This is not the most precise piece of phrasing but I assume that at least operations that don't mutate the state of the object (like reading the request query string) must be safe in background threads. (Before the request completes, of course.)